# problemas al cargar Excel a BD con c#

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

Estoy haciendo la carga de un archivo excel a un BD oracle, este es mi codigo, el problema que tengo es que cuando se ejecuta en un servidor IIS no se cargan todos los registros del archivo
en la BD, al parecer (no estoy seguro)cuando entra en el catch es cuando se detiene y ya no carga mas registros, como puedo de otra manera obtener los errores de formateo sin usar el try-catch, cabe 
señalar que cuando ejecuto el proyecto de manera local en mi pc este si se ejecuta bien y carga todos los registros

```html
private void CargaArchivos()
        {
            string Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";

            try
            {
                if (fuExcel.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
                {

                    String ConnExcel = "";
                    string HojaExcel = "";
                    string pathOriginal = Server.MapPath("Files/" + fuExcel.PostedFile.FileName);
                    if (File.Exists(pathOriginal))
                        File.Delete(pathOriginal);
                    fuExcel.SaveAs(pathOriginal);

                    string nombreArchivo = fuExcel.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();

                    if (fuExcel.PostedFile.FileName.Contains("xlsx"))
                        ConnExcel = "Provider=" + Provider + "; Data Source = " + pathOriginal + "; Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;READONLY=FALSE\";";
                    else
                        ConnExcel = "Provider=" + Provider + "; Data Source = " + pathOriginal + "; Extended Properties = \"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;READONLY=FALSE\";";

                    OleDbConnection ConnLocal = new OleDbConnection(ConnExcel);
                    ConnLocal.Open();
                    OleDbCommand cmdLocal = new OleDbCommand("", ConnLocal);
                    System.Data.DataTable dtExcelSheetName = ConnLocal.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    foreach (DataRow drtabla in dtExcelSheetName.Rows)
                        if (drtabla["Table_Name"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("LAYOUT") || drtabla["Table_Name"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("SHEET1") || drtabla["Table_Name"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("TABLE1"))
                        {
                            HojaExcel = drtabla["Table_Name"].ToString();
                            break;
                        }
                    if (HojaExcel == "")
                        HojaExcel = "Hoja1$";

                    OleDbDataAdapter dta = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + HojaExcel + "]", ConnLocal);

                    DataTable dtExcel = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    dta.Fill(dtExcel);


                    txtTotal.Text = dtExcel.Rows.Count.ToString();


                    int filas = 1;
                    int c = 0;

                    System.Data.DataTable dtSalida = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("AA", typeof(DateTime));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("BB", typeof(string));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("CC", typeof(int));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("DD", typeof(int));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("EE", typeof(string));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("FF", typeof(DateTime));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("GG", typeof(int));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("HH", typeof(string));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("II", typeof(string)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("JJ", typeof(float)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("KK", typeof(string)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("LL", typeof(int)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("MM", typeof(int)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("NN", typeof(float)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("OO", typeof(string)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("PP", typeof(int)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("QQ", typeof(string)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("RR", typeof(DateTime)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("SS", typeof(int));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("TT", typeof(float)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("UU", typeof(float)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("VV", typeof(string)).AllowDBNull = true;

                    float res_dou;
                    int i = 0;

                    foreach (DataRow dr in dtExcel.Rows)
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            DataRow row2 = dtSalida.NewRow();
                            if (float.TryParse(dr["UU"].ToString(), out res_dou) == false)
                            {
                                throw new Exception("Error al formatear");
                            }
                            row2["AA"] = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["AA"].ToString().Replace("a", "").Replace("m", "").Replace("p", "").Replace(".", "")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
                            row2["BB"] = dr["HR_TRANSACCION"].ToString().Replace(":", "");
                            row2["CC"] = dr["CVE_CARRIL"].ToString();
                            row2["DD"] = dr["NUM_EVENTO"].ToString();
                            row2["EE"] = dr["CVE_PZCOBRO"].ToString();
                            row2["FF"] = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["FCH_BASE"].ToString().Replace("a", "").Replace("m", "").Replace("p", "").Replace(".", "")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
                            row2["GG"] = dr["CVE_TRAM_CAM"].ToString();
                            row2["HH"] = dr["CVE_TVEHICULO"].ToString();
                            row2["II"] = dr["CVE_CLSVEHEJES_DIC"].ToString();
                            row2["JJ"] = DBNull.Value;
                            row2["KK"] = dr["NUM_TARJETA"].ToString();
                            row2["LL"] = DBNull.Value;
                            row2["MM"] = DBNull.Value;
                            row2["NN"] = DBNull.Value;
                            row2["OO"] = DBNull.Value;
                            row2["PP"] = Convert.ToInt32(dr["NUM_TRANSVAL_CAPUFE"]);
                            row2["QQ"] = DBNull.Value;
                            row2["RR"] = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["RR"].ToString().Replace("a", "").Replace("m", "").Replace("p", "").Replace(".", "")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                            row2["SS"] = dr["SEQ_TRANSIT"].ToString();
                            row2["TT"] = DBNull.Value;
                            row2["UU"] = res_dou;
                            row2["VV"] = nombreArchivo;
                            dtSalida.Rows.Add(row2);
                            i++;
                            Session["Procesado"] = i;
                            txtProcesado.Text = Session["Procesado"].ToString();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            lstMensaje.Items.Add("Error Fila: " + i + 1 + " -> " + ex.Message);
                        }


                    }



                    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
                    con.ConnectionString = "XXX";

                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        using (OracleBulkCopy bulkcopy = new OracleBulkCopy(con))
                        {

                            bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "tconsolida";
                            bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dtSalida);

                        }
                        con.Close();
                        con.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        lstMensaje.Items.Add("Error al hacer bulk-> " + ex.Message);
                    }


                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                lstMensaje.Items.Add("Error General: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: ¿Qué errores se obtienen en el `catch`?, ¿hay alguna manera en la que pueda comprobar qué diferencias hay entre el servidor IIS y su proyecto local?. Cuando he tenido este problema es *(o por temas de datos del Excel)* o porque faltaba algún campo en la tabla a guardar los datos...

Comment: porque haces un if del `Contains("xlsx")` si despues el provider es el mismo para ambos casos ?

Comment: para que sirve `Session["Procesado"] = i;` y porque asignas `txtProcesado.Text` si sabes que no veras reflejado un avance mientras estes en el servidor

Comment: @LeandroTuttini el if funciona para cuando se carga un archivo excel con extension xlsx o xls que son archivos excel mas antiguos, y del session tienes razon

Comment: es correcto que uses el `try...catch` para obtener los problemas que se generen, pero ya que asignas estos a un lista de mensajes, porque no visualizas el problema ?

Comment: ok pero donde cambias el valor de la variable `Provider ` sea antiguo o nuevo simpre pones el `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`

Comment: @LeandroTuttini en la propiedad "Extended Properties"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se agrega propiedad `IMEX=1` a cadena de conexión del excel